# Custom is_valid() Serializer Django

Tags: python, django

I need to write custom is_valid()
Below is my existing serializer class

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    u_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    age = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    preferredtime = serializers.DateTimeField()
    car = TableEvs() #here
    pref_pay_mode = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Model class for above car is :

```
class TableEvs(models.Model):
    ev_uid = models.IntegerField()
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

can someone confirm if its possible ?

Comment: you can, by define correctly Field in serializer, or any rule you want in method `validate` of serializer. But in this case i dont know mapping from TableEvs with UserSerializer? Can add more detail relation of it? or rule you want?

Comment: car field maps with ev_uid as ForeginKey .

Comment: You can override the is_valid method of the serializers.ModelSerializer class.